# Modal box stops working correctly after adding a second modal box

Tags: javascript

I have 2 buttons, one for Log In and 1 for Sign In. I have created 2 different modal boxes that contain the forms for Log In and Sign In. Unfortunately for some reason, as soon as I add the second modal box, the first one stops closing itself as soon I see click outside of it. I've created a codepen so you can see for yourself.

https://codepen.io/BozhidarSK/pen/zRmKbG

If you click on Sign Up and click anywhere else afterwards, the modal box will close, unfortunately this doesn't happen when you click Log In.

```js
var logInModal = document.getElementById('logInModal');
 var logInButton = document.getElementById("logIn");

 logInButton.onclick = function() {
     logInModal.style.display = "block";
 }

 window.onclick = function(event) {
     if (event.target == logInModal) {
         logInModal.style.display = "none";
     }
 }

 var signUpModal = document.getElementById('signUpModal');
 var signUpButton = document.getElementById("signUp");

 signUpButton.onclick = function() {
     signUpModal.style.display = "block";
 }

 window.onclick = function(event) {
     if (event.target == signUpModal) {
         signUpModal.style.display = "none";
     }
 }
```

```css
.modal {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    padding-top: 100px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li id='signUp'>Sign Up</li>
  <li id="logIn">Log In</li>
</ul>

<div id="logInModal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        sssssss
    </div>
</div>

<div id="signUpModal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        sssssss
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your problem can be reduced to: `var foo; foo = "A"; foo = "B"; console.log(foo);` - Why doesn't this print `A`?

Comment: Can you elaborate? I still don't see where my mistake is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first event listener is overridden. To fix the problem.

Try the following code.

```
    var logInModal = document.getElementById('logInModal');
    var logInButton = document.getElementById("logIn");

    logInButton.onclick = function() {
        logInModal.style.display = "block";
    }

    var signUpModal = document.getElementById('signUpModal');
    var signUpButton = document.getElementById("signUp");

    signUpButton.onclick = function() {
        signUpModal.style.display = "block";
    }

    window.onclick = function(event) {
        if (event.target == signUpModal) {
            signUpModal.style.display = "none";
        } else if (event.target == logInModal) {
             logInModal.style.display = "none";      
        }
    }
```

Here's the updated codepen [link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZrqBGE).

Comment: Oh my, how foolish of me. What Melpomene said makes sense now.

Answer (score 5):

you dont need to define windows.onclick method twice...

```
var logInModal = document.getElementById('logInModal');
var logInButton = document.getElementById("logIn");

logInButton.onclick = function() {
    logInModal.style.display = "block";
}

var signUpModal = document.getElementById('signUpModal');
var signUpButton = document.getElementById("signUp");

signUpButton.onclick = function() {
    signUpModal.style.display = "block";
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == logInModal) {
        logInModal.style.display = "none";
    }
    else if (event.target == signUpModal) {
        signUpModal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```